# Find conflict by using Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table which has a **StartTime** column of **DateTime** type. If there is less that 10 minutes between two rows I should consider that two rows as conflict. What I want to know is to check for that conflicts and show them with linq query.

Thanks for any help

Comment: please show us some code, what you have tried, so that we can assist you. also show us some eg of what has to be extracted from db

Answer (score 2):

I'd possibly do: (although this is in squared time)

```
var diffs = from x in times
            from y in times
            select (x - y).TotalMinutes;

return diffs.Any(x => x < 10);
```

For n-logn time it'd be better to sort first then compare pair-wise, and LINQ would be a little overkill for that.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is not the best method in this case.  Probably creating a for loop is better.  But here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("time", typeof(DateTime));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 20, 0) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 25, 0) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 30, 0) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 40, 0) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 45, 0) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 50, 0) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 56, 0) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 1, 58, 0) });

            List<DateTime> times = dt.AsEnumerable().Where((x, i) => (i > 0) && (x.Field<DateTime>("time") - dt.Rows[i - 1].Field<DateTime>("time")).TotalMinutes < 10).Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("time")).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```